# Django + VueJS: POST 403 Forbidden - CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, csrf

I am running Django + Django REST framework in the backend and Vue.js in the frontend. 
GET requests work fine, POST requests via Postman/Insomnia also do, but POST requests via the Vue.js frontend return an error in the Browser console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/ 403 (Forbidden)
{detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
```

This is how I get the CSRF token and then fetch a POST request:

*File: csrf_token.js:*

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
var CSRF_TOKEN = Cookies.get("csrftoken");
export { CSRF_TOKEN };
```

*File: api.service.js*:

```
import CSRF_TOKEN from "./csrf_token.js";

async function getJSON(response) {
  if (response.status === 204) return "";
  return response.json();
}

function apiService(endpoint, method, data) {
  const config = {
    credentials: "same-origin",
    method: method || "GET",
    body: data !== undefined ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "X-CSRFToken": CSRF_TOKEN
    }
  };
  return fetch(endpoint, config)
    .then(getJSON)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

export { apiService };
```

*MyComponent.vue:*

```
...
methods: {
  onSubmit() {
    apiService(endpoint, method, { content: this.content })
      .then(response_content => {
        console.log(response_content)   
      });
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, in my case it was an export/import issue.

```
export default CSRF_TOKEN;
```

instead of

```
export { CSRF_TOKEN };
```

made the trick